# How can I classify a person's score according to my discriminant variable, in a discriminant function? (multiple discriminant analysis)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, spss, discriminant-analysis

I'm doing a research on 5 types of entrepreneurship (dependent variable) and personality traits (5 independent variables). As you can tell, I did a discriminant analysis as a "plus" for my prior cluster analysis. I did all the statistical analysis and developed the discriminant functions. Now, I was wondering if there's like a cut-off criterion when I obtain a person's score in the discriminant function. I mean, for example, suppose that the independent variables X1 and X2 in a person are equal to 1 and 2, respectivebly, then:

D = 2(X1) + 3(X2)
D = 7

What does that 7 mean? In which categories of my dependent variables should that 7 be? Am I wrong? As far as I know, by reading some books, the I think the discriminant function is useful to tell us which of the independent variables are more important than others.

I hope you can understand me.

PD: My analyses were done on SPSS.

Cheers!

Comment: The program should tell you. I don't know SPSS (and questions about programs are off topic here) but I'd be amazed if a well-established program like that did not tell you this.  By itself "7" means nothing.

Comment: @PeterFlom , hi! Thanks for your response! I don't know where can I find those cut-offs in SPSS. The Output where I got the discriminant function is "Standardized Canonical Discriminant Function Coefficients", then there's other tables: "Structure Matrix", "Functions at Group Centroids", I don't know which of them can tell me the cut-off.

Comment: You should ask on an SPSS list (or call their tech support).